# How can I get time from ISO 8601 time format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, iso8601

This is my ISO formatted date. In here I want to get time like "11:00" by JavaScript.
I used this method:

```
new Date(Mydate).toLocaleString();
```

But it gave time as "16:30". Is there any format or method to do that in JavaScript? How can I get only time of that time zone.

```
var Mydate = "2012-10-16T11:00:28.556094Z";
```

Output will be the "11:00"

Answer (score 8):

Modern approach, using ECMAScript Internationalization API built in to Node.js and most modern browsers:

```
const myDate = "2012-10-16T11:00:28.556094Z";
const time = new Date(myDate).toLocaleTimeString('en',
                 { timeStyle: 'short', hour12: false, timeZone: 'UTC' });

// Output:  "11:00"
```

Older approach, using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com):

```
var myDate = "2012-10-16T11:00:28.556094Z";
var time = moment.utc(myDate).format("HH:mm");

// Output:  "11:00"
```

Comment: @BerkerYüceer - Original answer was written in 2013.  I updated it to show the modern approach that does not require Moment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
var date = new Date(Mydate);
var time = ConvertNumberToTwoDigitString(date.getUTCHours()) + 
           ":" + ConvertNumberToTwoDigitString(date.getUTCMinutes());

// Returns the given integer as a string and with 2 digits
// For example: 7 --> "07"
function ConvertNumberToTwoDigitString(n) {
    return n > 9 ? "" + n : "0" + n;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply . But in here output is 16:30. I need to get "11.00"

Comment: Then use `getUTCHours()` and `getUTCMinutes()` instead

Comment: You will also need to zero-pad the minutes with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I forget where I got this:

```
// --- Date ---
// convert ISO 8601 date string to normal JS Date object
// usage: (new Date()).setISO8601( "ISO8601 Time" )

Date.prototype.setISO8601 = function(string) {
  var d, date, offset, regexp, time;
  regexp = "([0-9]{4})(-([0-9]{2})(-([0-9]{2})" + 
           "(T([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})(:([0-9]{2})(\.([0-9]+))?)?" + 
           "(Z|(([-+])([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2})))?)?)?)?";
  d      = string.match(new RegExp(regexp));
  offset = 0;
  date   = new Date(d[1], 0, 1);
  if (d[3])  date.setMonth(d[3] - 1);
  if (d[5])  date.setDate(d[5]);
  if (d[7])  date.setHours(d[7]);
  if (d[8])  date.setMinutes(d[8]);
  if (d[10]) date.setSeconds(d[10]);
  if (d[12]) date.setMilliseconds(Number("0." + d[12]) * 1000);
  if (d[14]) {
    offset = (Number(d[16]) * 60) + Number(d[17]);
    offset *= (d[15] === '-' ? 1 : -1);
  }
  offset -= date.getTimezoneOffset();
  time = Number(date) + (offset * 60 * 1000);
  return this.setTime(Number(time));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to grab the time from ISO date.

```
let Mydate = '2012-10-16T11:00:28.556094Z';
let result = Mydate .match(/\d\d:\d\d/);
console.log(result[0]);
```

The output will be,

```
11:00
```

Answer (score 1):

be aware that older implementation of the `toLocaleTimeString` can behave differently depending on the browser's implementation.

Date: 2021-September-09

> The locales and options arguments customize the behavior of the
> function and let applications specify which language formatting
> conventions should be used. In older implementations that ignore the
> locales and options arguments, the locales and the form of the string
> returned will be entirely implementation-dependent.

The implementation I recently used:

```js
function getTimeFromISODateString(isoDateString) {
  const date = new Date(isoDateString);
  const hours = `0${date.getUTCHours()}`.slice(-2);
  const minutes = `0${date.getUTCMinutes()}`.slice(-2);
  const seconds = `0${date.getUTCSeconds()}`.slice(-2);
  return `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer failed for me for any time of 00:34 as it got changed to 24:34

```
const time = new Date(myDate).toLocaleTimeString('en',
                 { timeStyle: 'short', hour12: false, timeZone: 'UTC' });
```

It would seem this is a better solution, at least for me.

```
new Date(value).toLocaleTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit' });
```

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString

Answer (score 0):

use this to separate date and time ONLY if you don't need to use time zone

```js
const separateDateTime = (dateTime: string) => {
    const date = dateTime.split("T")[0];
    const time = dateTime.split("T")[1].split(".")[0]
    return { date, time };
  }

// how to use it
const myDate = "2012-10-16T11:00:28.556094Z";
const dateTimeObj = separateDateTime(myDate)

console.log(dateTimeObj.time)
```